# what cells in 4X4 grid are next to each other?

Tags: language-agnostic, multidimensional-array

i have an array that stores indexes of cells in a 4X4 grid, 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. I know that directly next to item 0 is item 1 (to the right) and item 4 (below). How would i write a function that returns indexes of cells that are directly next to the index passed in?

```
function getCellsAround(0)
{
     should return 1 and 4
}
```

Comment: you just described it to us in English.  You need to generalize and convert it to code.  Are you struggling with a particular point?

Comment: Looks like you want something like `+ 1` and `- 1 % 4` in x and y coordinates? You'd also need two parameters to the function

Comment: Well its -4 (unless you're on the top edge), +4 (unless you're on the bottom edge), -1 (unless you're on the left edge), +1 (unless you're on the right edge). Doesn't sound too difficult, why not have a go and post your code if you get stuck.

Comment: yes, im struggling with determining how to get values 1 and 4 programatically

Comment: jahhaj, its not, theres more then 1 item next to index passed

Comment: 0+1 == 1, 0+4 == 4. I don't see where the difficulty is.

Comment: You seem to be missing a few language tags.

Comment: @nuway: Sure there's more than one item, is that's what is puzzling you? If so then look at the answer below.

Comment: **If you don't care about the language, tag it as "language-agnostic"**, don't just enumerate all languages you can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<Point> getPointsAround(Point p, Rectangle r) {
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
        for(int dy=-1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            if(dx!=0 || dy !=0) {
                Point point = new Point(p.x+dx, p.y+dy);
                if(r.contains(point)) {
                    points.add(point);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Something like that? That uses x, y coordinates (Point class) rather than just:

(1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework to me, so here's a general idea.

Make a function for each type of neighbor.  Since you wrote so many languages, not sure what you are actually using.  Here's java

```
private Integer getTopNeighbor(int ind) // ....
private Integer getBottomNeighbor(int ind) // ....
private Integer getLeftNeighbor(int ind) // ....
private Integer getRightNeighbor(int ind) // ....

public Integer[] getAllNeighbors(int ind) // use the four above to determine
```

Then some of these will likely be null (such as the first index 0 won't have a left or top neighbor).  So check all of these and return the non-null ones.

Just to get you started, getRightNeighbor will be ind + 1 with some boundary checking.